# How to group background-color and border color property from different elements into the same css class?

Tags: html, css

For example, I have a orange label with triangle at left and right:

```css
.tdLeft {
  border-right: 0.5em solid orange;
}

.tdMiddle {
  background-color: orange;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.tdRight {
  border-left: 0.5em solid orange;
}

.tdSide {
  border-top: 0.5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0.5em solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 50px">
  <tr>
    <td class="tdLeft tdSide"></td>
    <td class="tdMiddle">testing</td>
    <td class="tdRight tdSide"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

now if I want to change the color of this label, I need to set the tdLeft,tdMiddle and tdRight from "orange" to other color (e.g.:red) separately, is where anyway to group the background-color and border color property into the same css so that "orange" can appear once only in the css file?

Comment: As long as you are abusing tables for layout purposes, you should not be bothering with such CSS issues already …

Comment: Can be done without CSS variables though, as long as you have at least two nested elements - `currentColor` “to the rescue” would be the motto (and research keyword.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *[CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)* to change the *value* only once:

```css
:root {
  --color: red; /* adjust */
}

.tdLeft {
  border-right: 0.5em solid var(--color);
}

.tdMiddle {
  background-color: var(--color);
  font-size: 30px;
}

.tdRight {
  border-left: 0.5em solid var(--color);
}

.tdSide {
  border-top: 0.5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0.5em solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 50px">
  <tr>
    <td class="tdLeft tdSide"></td>
    <td class="tdMiddle">testing</td>
    <td class="tdRight tdSide"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

For browsers that [support](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20variables) it.

Otherwise you'll always have to do it at least twice, if applied to multiple different properties.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using only one element, and pseudo-elements `::before` and `::after`.
I also used a CSS variable for the color:

```css
table {
  --color: orange;
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}

.myTD {
  position: relative;
  border: 0 solid transparent;
  border-width: 0.5em 0;
  background-color: var(--color);
  font-size: 30px;
}

.myTD::before,
.myTD::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.5em;
  bottom: -0.5em;
  border: 1em solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent var(--color);
}

.myTD::before {
  left: -1em;
  border-left: 0;
}

.myTD::after {
  right: -1em;
  border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" style="font-size:50px;">
  <tr>
    <td class="myTD">testing</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can use nesting of css variables too like the following. It is a modified answer as suggested by @VXp:

```
:root{
    --color: orange;
    --border: 0.5em solid var(--color);
    --transparent: transparent;
    --solid: 0.5em solid var(--transparent);
}

.tdLeft{
  border-right:var(--border);
}
.tdMiddle{
  background-color:var(--color);
  font-size:30px;
}
.tdRight{
  border-left:var(-border);
}
.tdSide{
  border-top:var(--border) var(--transparent);
  border-bottom:var(--solid);
}
```